# VueJs computed property without caching

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have a component which is an input field that accept three cases and translate them to a inner state (number) :

- Input: *nothing (empty string)*; State: *undefined*; Class: *is-empty*; Value: *empty string*
- Input: *any positive number*; State: *the positive number*; Class: ; Value: *the positive number*
- Input: *`-`*; State: *-1*; Class: *is-unknown*; Value: *`-`*
- Otherwise: State: *-2*; Class: *is-invalid*; Value: *empty string*

This component has an `output` computed property with a setter that change the inner state and a getter that returns either the number, the dash or an empty string when invalid based on the inner state. The special case is for the invalid inputs where I would like to keep the field empty.

For the first invalid character it works well, however the next ones are displayed into the field. I suspect that the value is cached because the inner state stay on `invalid` and thus the cache is used.

```
<template>
  <input v-model="output" v-bind:class="state"/>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'TsResult',
  props: ['result'],
  data: function() {
    return {
      res: this.result
    }
  },
  computed: {
    state: function() {
      // ..
      if (this.res === -2) {
        return 'is-invalid'
      } else if (this.res === -1) {
        return 'is-unknown'
      }
      // ...
    },
    'output': {
      set: function(newVal) {
        //.. 
        if (isInvalid(newVal)) {
           this.res = -2;
        } else if (isUnknwon(newVal)) {
           this.res = -1;
        }
        // ...
      },
      get: function() {
        if (this.res === -2 ) { // Invalid
          return ''
        } else if (this.res === -1) { // Unknown
          return '-'
        } 
        // ...
      }
    }
</script>
```

Using a method instead of a computed getter is not applicable because I need the setter to perform the validation.

And using a watcher is not a good idea because the invalid state change the input value (by setting an empty string) and re-trigger the watcher that accept the empty string. So the invalid state is never shown.

Can I disable the caching on this computed property or is there a better alternative ?

A possible hack is to decrement my internal state for invalid states so that the inner state change and the value is recomputed. But I would like to have a better solution.

Comment: pls provide code sample

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Passing a `cache` attribute set to `false` should disable the caching for the computed property. For details see [issue #1189 - Make computed property caching optional](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/1189) and the [relevant commit](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/commit/dbb3faced31fdfaea69872f259d6b07e9f11feaf).

Maybe you could overlay an invisible input field receiving the actual keypresses and output the computed property to the lower, displayed one?

What about splitting the `v-model` in `v-bind` and `v-on:input`, like roughly (added missing functions to test it):

```
<template>
  <input v-bind:value="output_computed()" v-on:input="on_input($event.target.value)" v-bind:class="state"/>
</template>

<script>
function isValid(val) {
  return parseInt(val) != NaN && parseInt(val) >= 0;
}

function isInvalid(val) {
  return parseInt(val) == NaN || parseInt(val) < 0;
}

function isUnknown(val) {
  return !(isValid(val) || isInvalid(val));
}

export default {
  name: "TsResult",
  props: ["result"],
  data() {
    return {
      res: this.result,
      v: ""
    };
  },
  methods: {
    output_computed() {
      if (this.res === -2) {
        // Invalid
        return "";
      } else if (this.res === -1) {
        // Unknown
        return "-";
      } else if (this.res === -3) {
        return "";
      } else if (this.res === 0) {
        return this.v;
      }
    },
    on_input(newVal) {
      if (isInvalid(newVal)) {
        this.res = -2;
      } else if (isUnknown(newVal)) {
        this.res = -1;
      } else if (newVal === "") {
        this.res = -3;
      } else if (isValid(newVal)) {
        this.res = 0;
        this.v = newVal;
      }
      this.$emit("input", this.output_computed());
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

You can see it live [here on codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/s/81vyxoozq9)

Comment: Looks like this has been removed: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/migration.html#cache-false-deprecated

Comment: it's deprecated but it should be still there. If you want to avoid it, would be suitable for you to use a property with a setter for the validation and a regular method for the output (thus avoiding caching)?

Comment: Don't want to use deprecated features. The method plus setter solution does not works. Can we have a computed setter and a method for the same property ?

Comment: no, but why can't you use different names for the two? The setter would set an internal variable and the method would return it

Comment: How can I tell to bind one property as input and another as output in my template ? My template is an `<input v-model="output">` (see edits in my question). **Edit:** Did not read your answer. Will try it

Comment: The `v-model` is roughly equivalent to the `v-bind` + `v-on:input`. Customizing the two differently should obtain your objective of separating the logic/values of input and output.

Comment: The only drawback with your solution is that the invalid input is still displayed

Comment: but does `output_computed()` produce the desired output or not? What invalid input do you see displayed?

Comment: I've updated the example in my answer. You can see it live [here in codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/s/81vyxoozq9)